# Does .bashrc contain syntax errors?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, bashrc

In the Ubuntu 18.04 LT .bashrc file there is the following:

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
```

Isn't xterm-color) an instance of unbalanced parentheses? And why does the line end with two semicolons?

To be clear, this is not something I wrote. It's in the virgin file, not edited by me.

If there are syntax errors, to whom should I report this?

Comment: There's an easy way to check if this is a syntax error: just run it, and Bash will tell you whether it is a syntax error. In fact, this will be run every time you open a terminal, so you just have to look if there is a syntax error printed every time you open the terminal.

Comment: if it's an error then you'll get a report every time you open a new terminal

Comment: Prior research might have included simply looking up the syntax for switch/case in Bash, through which you would have quickly discovered that this is entirely normal.

Comment: @JörgWMittag If you don't know what a script does, running it might be a not so clever idea. Checking it with `bash -n .bashrc` is probably better

Comment: @ChatterOne: It gets executed every single time you open a terminal; if there is something malicious about it, it will already have happened a long time ago.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is the standard, correct syntax for a bash `case` statement(known abstractly as a [switch statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement) in general programming), albeit perhaps an odd syntax when compared to C, Java, or other languages.

From [The Linux Documentation Project](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html):

> Nested if statements might be nice, but as soon as you are confronted
>   with a couple of different possible actions to take, they tend to
>   confuse. For the more complex conditionals, use the case syntax:
>
> ```
> case EXPRESSION in CASE1) COMMAND-LIST;; CASE2) COMMAND-LIST;; ... CASEN) COMMAND-LIST;; esac
> ```

Comment: (the information is also available from `help case` command.)

Comment: There can actually be an optional opening parenthesis in front of any of the patterns, i.e. `case $var in (foo) echo something;; esac`. Bash's command line help doesn't mention that, but the [online reference manual has it](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html) (Along with an example `case` statement, too...)

Comment: Not just in `bash`; the [POSIX shell specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05) allows an optional opening `(` as well.